# Why this SonarQube rule? First sentence of Javadoc is incomplete (period is missing) or not present

Tags: sonarqube, javadoc

I get this SonarQube message in my project:

> First sentence of Javadoc is incomplete (period is missing) or not
>   present. (L39)

Why does SonarQubetell me to end the first sentence in my JavaDoc with a period?
I consider this bad style - like in a list you would also not end every item with a period. Or a header in a newspaper - there would be no period.

And it is not an 'Info' type but a 'Major' tpye. What the actual ...? That doesn't make any sense for me.

Does anyone understand where this rule comes from? Is there a database of reasonings for SonarQube-rules on the SonarQube-website (or somewhere else in the internet)? I couldn't find anything alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to Write Doc Comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-137868.html#firstsentence) in the Javadoc Tool's guide

> The first sentence of each doc comment should be a summary sentence, containing a concise but complete description of the API item.

...

> The Javadoc tool copies this first sentence to the appropriate member, class/interface or package summary

...

> This sentence ends at the first period that is followed by a blank, tab, or line terminator, or at the first tag (as defined below)

So the basic answer is that you need the first period to allow the Javadoc tool to know how to provide the summary of your Javadoc.

You can check the details (background, suggestions, severity) for each rule in SonarQube and can change their severity and deactivate them through the 'Rules' tab shown across the top bar of the SonarQube UI.

Comment: "or at the first tag". This makes it sound like the period is not quite so mandatory after all (to have well-formed Javadoc).